# TFS 2017: Send email option on changeset review is NOT available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

After installing TFS 2017, I didn't find the send email option on changeset review functionality. It was there in TFS 2013, but I didn't find after installing TFS 2017.

**TFS 2013:**

See image:

[image]

**This option was available in TFS 2013, BUT I didn't found in TFS 2017**.

Where to enable this option in TFS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that this button is removed from TFS 2017. This feature do not supported in TFS 2017 any more.

I have submit a feedback about this issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/58100/tfs-2017-send-email-option-on-changeset-review-is.html

Comment: Thanks very much @Tingting0929-MSFT. I really appreciate your help.